# YouTube API v3 filtering embeddable videos

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In YouTube API v3 documentation there are parameters like `regionCode`, `videoEmbeddable`, `videoSyndicated`. But it seems none of them are working properly. I want to exclude VEVO videos from my search results. So it should be possible with `videoEmbeddable='true'` parameter. But this parameter makes no difference to my search results.

Using API v2 I could remove VEVO vidoes by adding the parameter `format=5` but this parameter is not available in v3.

Does anyone know how to do this using v3?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I am struggling with the same thing right now. videoEmbeddable and videoSyndicated seem to do nothing to the results.

Comment: No. I had to filter search result by checking username. If username contains "VEVO" I removed it. This is not the best way and it's not 100% successful but most of the time it gets the job done. I couldn't find a way to do it with v3 API.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a search->list, you can set [videoSyndicated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoSyndicated) to true.

Comment: I am using this flag and am still getting videos that cannot be played on my site. The 2nd result for related videos to ID: SZoX6Q0UK8A is egYMZKpENCg. When I try to play it, I get the error: "This video contains content from SME. It is restricted from playback on certain sites. Watch on YouTube."

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `&type=video&videoEmbeddable=true` although this might be the same as the previous solution, it worked for. You might have a more specific problem, as if seems.

Comment: I am seeing exactly this problem as well. I also receive non-embeddable videos with exactly the query `&type=video&videoEmbeddable=true` as suggested. Looks like a bug in the api to me.