# Android YouTubePlayer Restricted Videos

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

All of a sudden (May 10th 2016) the Android YouTubePlayer refuses to play certain music videos (VEVO for example). I know this has come up before and then gone away again but I wanted to know if anyone else has seen this change today and if there are any workarounds? I've seen others fix this with Webview based YouTube players but not with the Android YouTubePlayer. Any ideas?

[How can I work around YouTube API embed restrictions like other websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917469/how-can-i-work-around-youtube-api-embed-restrictions-like-other-websites)

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175720/youtube-api-v3-filtering-embeddable-videos

Comment: Thanks, I had implemented filtering way back when this first occurred but for the last couple of years it had not been an issue and no filtering was necessary until yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check this project
https://github.com/theScrabi/NewPipe
they manage to play Vevo videos, i belive they use [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/).

This restriction seems to be happening to most android apps that use youtube API, Shazam for example.

Comment: Yes, I saw the same problem on Shazam confirming it wasn't something my app was doing. Thanks for that. I'll take a look at NewPipe

Comment: Took a look at NewPipe - works very well for my purposes. Thanks.

Comment: No problem :) , on a side note, i belive vevo videos are working again on shazam.

Comment: So, in conclusion, no sooner had I done the work to integrate the NewPipe approach displaying videos in a VideoView, the YouTubePlayer starts playing Vevo videos again, meaning Google has removed the restrictions. Now I've done most of the work I think the best way forward is to have both implemented and have some runtime adaptation should videos become blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with the youtube player for Android since yesterday, i'm looking for a solution too but nothing still. I tried to create a new browser key but nothing changes. I've never had this kind of problem before.

Edit: I confirm that now VEVO & Company videos are playing fine again on my YouTube Android Player. Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: As Ric said above, it's an issue for all apps, including Shazam. I verified it by trying to play an embedded video on that app - same problem. Feels like this may not get reversed and a Webview approach may be required. I'm going to take a closer look over the next few days so will update shortly